# Strings and Loops Practice Test

Tags: java, string, loops, indexing, string-concatenation

I'm slightly confused on this test question. I made a chart of the values of i , j, and the string. I got "nbearig", but my runtime is printing out numbers. I'm not sure where I went wrong. ++i , --j means that they were incre/decremented before the code after the for loop right?

```
public class AlGore {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mystery = "mnerigpaba";
        String solved = "";
        int len = mystery.length();
        for (int i = 0, j = len - 1; i < len/2; ++i, --j) {
            solved += mystery.charAt(i) + mystery.charAt(j);
        }
        System.out.println(solved);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I've been told that this is integral math. I thought that the charAt(i) function will return a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure where I went wrong. ++i , --j means that they were incre/decremented before the code after the for loop right?

1)  They were preincremented / predecremented respectively.

2)  It happened after each execution of the loop body.

> my compiler is printing out numbers.

No it isn't.  The compiler is compiling your code!!!  The JVM is printing numbers ... when you *run* the code.

To understand the reason why, take a careful look at this:

```
 solved += mystery.charAt(i) + mystery.charAt(j);
```

This is equivalent to

```
 solved = solved + ( mystery.charAt(i) + mystery.charAt(j) );
```

Now the expression in brackets performs a numeric addition of a character to a character.  According to the rules of Java expressions, that gives an `int` value.  So the entire expression becomes:

```
 solved = String.concat(
         solved, 
         Integer.toString(mystery.charAt(i) + mystery.charAt(j));
```

---

> I thought that the charAt(i) function will return a string?

No.  It returns a `char` ... just like the method name "charAt" implies.  `String` and `char` are fundamentally different types.

---

Comment: That is a good exam question, it tests how well you understand loops, and how well you understand Java expression semantics.

Comment: so for example, the first case is i = 1 , j = 9. Therefore it would be String.concat (solved, Integer.toString(mystery.charAt(1) + mystery.charAt(9))

Comment: mystery.charAt(1) = "n"     mystery.charAt(9) = "b"    How would be get integer values for these though? Is "a" = 1 , "b" = 2 ? etc.? My book does not really explain this concept well.

Comment: Not exactly.  `mystery.charAt(1) = 'n' and mystery.charAt(9) = 'b' `.  Those values are `char`.  You add them by promoting them to integers, and adding them.  The result is an `int`.

Comment: I think I might not understand the charAt function well. In my book it is defined as a function which takes in an index (integer) parameter and returns  the character in the string which corresponds to that index. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You are not missing anything about `charAt`.  What you are missing is a proper understanding of how Java expressions work.  And (apparently) that `String` and `char` are *fundamentally different*.

Comment: Oh, I see. Char and string are totally different concepts. the character 'a' differs from string "a"?  Therefore, this is an integer expression instead of a String concatenation.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to figure this out myself as I think that might be the best way for me to understand Java expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing integer math (because `char` is an [integral type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)),

```
// solved += mystery.charAt(i) + mystery.charAt(j);
solved += Character.toString(mystery.charAt(i))
        + Character.toString(mystery.charAt(j));
```

That way you are performing `String` concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

`mystery.charAt(i) + mystery.charAt(j);` will add the numeric values of those two characters. You can force string concatenation by adding `"" +` before:

```
solved += "" + mystery.charAt(i) + mystery.charAt(j);
```